# How do I get the file name from a String containing just a path in Java?

Tags: java

What is the easiest way to get the csv file name from a path without knowing the filename? Tried many ways, couldn't get one working. Can one please help me.

```
  String filePath = "/app/data/test/in/*.csv";
  Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
  Path fileName = path.getFileName();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Files#list`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#list(java.nio.file.Path)) to list all files in a directory.

Then, you can filter that to only get CSV files and get one of them:

```java
try(Stream<Path> fileStream = Files.list(Path.of("/app/data/test/in/"))){
    Optional<Path> file = fileStream
        .filter(file -> file.toString().endsWith(".csv"))//only look at CSV files
        .findAny();//get one if them
    file.ifPresent(csvPath -> {
        //do something with it
    })
}
```

If you want to make use of all CSV files in the given directory, you can use something like `toList` instead of `findAny`.

Answer (score 1):

For a more general answer use

```
Files.newDirectoryStream(Path dir, String glob)
```

which interprets a shell-style glob pattern into a `PathMatcher` to scan a directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Built-in File class

just use File.getName()

```
File f = new File("C:\\Hello\\AnotherFolder\\The File Name.PDF");
System.out.println(f.getName());
```

Another one method is :  Apache Commons IO‘s FilenameUtils class can “intelligently” extract the filename from different path formats (Include the artificat / module in your pom and can write the below code).

```
String filenameLinux = FilenameUtils.getName(PATH_LINUX);
assertEquals(EXPECTED_FILENAME_LINUX, filenameLinux);
                                                         
String filenameWin = FilenameUtils.getName(PATH_WIN);
assertEquals(EXPECTED_FILENAME_WIN, filenameWin);
```